# validation error "id" must be a single token

Tags: w3c-validation

I was testing my site on W3C validator when I found some errors like:

> "id" must be a single token

I've been wondering what's the fix but couldn't get an answer so if u can fix that would be appreciated.

Here's the code that gives me the error:

```
<form action='' id='contact form'>
```

Comment: Your second question is a separate one. It seems that you already [asked it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20992020/1591669). I removed this one from your question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that `id` should look like this:

```
<form action='' id='contact_form'>
```

E. g. without any whitespaces in value of `id` attribute. Also, it should be unique.

You haven't specified whether you are validating your document against HTML4 or HTML5. And there are some differences in specs for `id` in HTML4 and HTML5 - you can read about both here:

*HTML 5:*

- http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute

*HTML 4.0:*

- http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2
- http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#type-name

Comment: it fixed the first part .. thx alot 
do u know why the w3c source for my site is different from my actual html ( it contains extra scripts and codes )